# Adding multiple effects to a photo

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, cgimage

How can I add several effects to a picture? I have the following code that adds an effect to a photo:

```
func applyEffects(name: String, n: Float) {
    filter.setValue(self.cImage, forKeyPath: kCIInputImageKey)
    filter.setValue(n, forKeyPath: name)

    let result = filter.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage
    let cgImage = CIContext.init(options: nil).createCGImage(result, from: result.extent)

    self.customImage = UIImage.init(cgImage: cgImage!)
}

func brightness(n: Float) {
    self.applyEffects(name: kCIInputBrightnessKey, n: n)
}

func contrast(n: Float) {
    self.applyEffects(name: kCIInputContrastKey, n: n)
}

func saturation(n: Float) {
    self.applyEffects(name: kCIInputSaturationKey, n: n)
}
```

But when I want to apply the second effect, the first one disappears. How can I overlay two or more effects on each other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using `CIColorControls` as your filter.

You need to pass **all three** values into your call:

```
// The documentation doesn't give a default value for contrast, but for the others, I'm setting the defaults

var brightness:Float = 1
var contrast:Float = 1
var saturation:Float = 1


func applyEffects() {

    filter.setValue(self.cImage, forKeyPath: kCIInputImageKey)
    filter.setValue(brightness, forKeyPath: kCIInputBrightnessKey)
    filter.setValue(contrast, forKeyPath: kCIInputContrastKey)
    filter.setValue(saturation, forKeyPath: kCIInputSaturationKey)

    let result = filter.value(forKey: kCIOutputImageKey) as! CIImage
    let cgImage = CIContext.init(options: nil).createCGImage(result, from: result.extent)

    self.customImage = UIImage.init(cgImage: cgImage!)

}

func brightness(n: Float) {
    brightness = n
    applyEffects()
}

func contrast(n: Float) {
    contrast = n
    applyEffects()
}

func saturation(n: Float) {
    saturation = n
    applyEffects()
}
```

A suggestion:

If you are trying to use "real-time" updating via UISliders, use a GLKView and send in the CIImage directly. It uses the GPU, and performance on a device is greatly increased. You can always create a UIImage for saving, messaging, etc.

Comment: Thank you. Can I use GLKView  with UIViewController?

Comment: I do. GLKViews are a subclass of UIView. https://www.objc.io/issues/21-camera-and-photos/core-image-intro/ At the top of this article on CoreImage is a link to a GitHub that uses it. About halfway down (Improving Performance with OpenGL) is a pretty good explanation on how to use it.